# Grails Google-chart plugin font size

Tags: javascript, grails, google-visualization

I have written the following code to display a pie chart with the Google-chart plugin on grails:

```
<body>
<div align="center">
<g:pieChart title='Open Position Chart' labels="${pieChartLabels}" fill="${'bg,s,ffffff'}"
size="${[600,350]}" dataType='simple' data='${pieChartValues}' colors="${pieChartColours}" />
</div>
```

where pieChartLabels, pieChartValues and pieChartColours are array lists defined in a controller.  The code is working fine except that the title and the words on the chart are too small.  I was wondering if there is a way to set the fontsize?  I have tried adding fontSize="12" to the tag but it didn't work.

Cheers,
Eunice

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work with Grails, but in the standard javascript Google Visualization API, you would set the "fontSize" option for the PieChart.

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning the fontSize to the enclosing div tag.